# Execute the newest .exe file in folder via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try to execute `.exe` file which I previously copied in folder by using this command:

```
Invoke-Item “C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Desktop\R_OInstaller_2015_CL287638x64.exe”
```

But I need a command which gives me ability to execute the *newest file* in a folder:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Desktop" -Filter '*.exe' | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1 | Invoke-Item "Path\To\The\Item.exe" -Filter "what should I type here"
```

For example I have `R_OInstaller_2015_CL287638x64.exe` which I copied yesterday and `R_OInstaller_2015_CL287639x64.exe` which I copied today. I need to execute the file I copied today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Invoke-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113345) cmdlet takes a `Path` parameter so you can just pipe the item to it:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Desktop" -Filter '*.exe' | 
    Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    Select -First 1 | 
    Invoke-Item
```